# Node, Sequelize, Epilogue - Cannot Set Headers after they are sent to client

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am following a blog for learning purpose where I faced

> Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)

I have no idea on what caused the issue even after following the blog.

Can anyone help me solve this issue

index.js file,

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const initializeDatabase = require('./database')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const startServer = async () => {
  await initializeDatabase(app)

  const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000
  await promisify(app.listen).bind(app)(port)
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
}

startServer()
```

database.js file,

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const epilogue = require('epilogue')

const database = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: './test.sqlite',
  // operatorsAliases: false
})

const Part = database.define('parts', {
  partNumber: Sequelize.STRING,
  modelNumber: Sequelize.STRING,
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT
})

const initializeDatabase = async (app) => {
  epilogue.initialize({ app, sequelize: database })

  epilogue.resource({
    model: Part,
    endpoints: ['/parts', '/parts/:id']
  })

  await database.sync()
}

module.exports = initializeDatabase
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That error comes from one of your Express routes.  You don't show any of your Express routes so it's hard for us to know what to suggest.

Comment: You must have set response headers somewhere and again you are trying to send them.

Comment: In package.json am using a Sequelize version of 5.21.5 and it is not working. When I use the Sequelize version 4.38.0 the application is working as expected